# A stitch on a circle in Firefox using border-radius and border: dashed

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to style a half-circle with a stitch pattern.

But with my current code it is not getting the dashed pattern on the outside (I know that it is `border-radius` that is doing this).

Chrome is producing a correct result, but in Firefox I get the following result:

[image: Current Result]

My current code:

```
a#middle-left-circle{
    display:block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 180px;
    background: #117300;
    border-radius: 0 180px 180px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 180px 180px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 180px 180px 0;
    border: 2px dashed  #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #117300;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, must be an issue with some of the CSS that you haven't posted: https://jsfiddle.net/Loy41h55/ Edit: Looks like it works in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a known bug that Firefox fails to render dashed borders around border-radiuses:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

The bug currently has a status of "ASSIGNED", so with any luck it might be fixed soon.

---

After doing more research, there appears to be a workaround that involves using the `div:before` pseudoelement - see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smey7/7/) for a demo. Credit to [GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/gcyrillus) for this solution.